# Error installing webkit though everything needed is up to current date?

Tags: ruby, cmake, webkit

I'm trying to install Webkit so that i may use some of the features that come with it but i keep running into this error.

```
./build-webkit --debug --gtk

    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    -- Could NOT find Ruby (missing:  RUBY_INCLUDE_DIR RUBY_CONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable version "2.3.0", minimum required is "1.8.7")
    CMake Error at Source/cmake/FindCairo.cmake:65 (message):
      Required version (1.10.2) is higher than found version ()
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:29 (find_package)
      CMakeLists.txt:151 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/naomi/Desktop/Webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? (I did make sure Cmake, Ruby and such are up to date )

Comment: `Could NOT find Ruby (missing:  RUBY_INCLUDE_DIR RUBY_CONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable version "2.3.0", minimum required is "1.8.7")` means that Ruby library is found (`found suitable version` ...), but its headers aren't. Looks like you forgot to install devel package for Ruby.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just find ruby devel package for your distro, and install it.

Comment: the devel packages are installed. Still running into the same issue.

Comment: The difference is its error is in Cmake now apperently. Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
CMake Error at Source/cmake/FindCairo.cmake:65 (message):
  Required version (1.10.2) is higher than found version ()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:29 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:151 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/naomi/Desktop/Webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: As new error source is located in `Source/cmake/FindCairo.cmake`, you have problem with `Cairo` library.